# Difficulty styling width of matSelect

Tags: css, angular-material2

https://plnkr.co/edit/aUYfOBJ0MdywKW2pphOM?p=preview

```
<md-select placeholder="food" style=""><!-- no width stylings that work -->
    <md-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{ food.viewValue }}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Please see above plunker. I am having a lot of difficulty styling the width of the md-select with placeholder of 'food' . Why can't I do a style="" in the md-select tag? I have tried targeting this same div with a class with no response. I have also tried using the .md-select-trigger class that is visible in F12 tools of chrome, firefox, and ie edge. Nothing.

The only thing that works is deselecting the min-width or flex space-around of the .md-select-trigger class that is available in the tools area of browser.

I am not sure what I am dealing with here.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything stopping you from using `style="/* What you want*/"`, e.g. [this plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wqg1vvxE2DINhetzL28e?p=preview)

Comment: @Aeveus No, I don't think its a plunker thing. Same thing on my local. I have tried style="min-width: 10px", style="width: 10px", etc. , to show noticeable change in width, nothing.

Comment: You're trying to change something outside the scope of the current component. Angular has [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#view-encapsulation), which means styles defined in this component won't bleed into different components. You could override this via a global styles file, or turn view encapsulation off (even though, this is not recommended).

Comment: I just want to change this width locally to fit a styling use case. It looks like the link there discusses the extra attributes that get outputted with view encapsulation. Looks like targeting these is the way, correct? I can still target these styles in my component?

Comment: @Aeveus, you got it. I had to do md-select /deep/ md-select-trigger (the md-select-trigger may have been a class). I am away from my computer but wanted to share the knowledge and thank you for your help.

Comment: deep clone syntax worked for me

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55293532/7173194) worked for fixing width of mat-select

Answer (score 11):

Might be a bit late, but anyway...
To do this properly, you need to set the [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) to None on your component:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './my.component.html' ,
    styleUrls: ['./my.component.css'], 
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Then in your component css you can just do this:

```
.mat-select-trigger { min-width: 50px; }
```

From the link I posted:

> View Encapsulation = None means that Angular does no view
>   encapsulation. Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping
>   rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This
>   is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the
>   HTML.

Comment: works to increase the size, but the placeholder is not expanded... still the correct solution.

Answer (score 5):

To add to purwa astawa's answer you can use /deep/ in your components css to change the .mat-select-trigger min-width

```
.mat-select /deep/ .mat-select-trigger {
  min-width: 60px;
}
```

This is because .mat-select-trigger is being styled within the md-select module which is not normally accessible by your component.

The above method will soon be depricated. Use `ViewEncapsulation.None` instead. [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation)

Comment: The `/deep/` shadow-piercing descendant combinator is marked as deprecated. See my answer.

Comment: Until then `::ng-deep` should be preferred over ` /deep/ ` for a broader compatibility with the tools. **Quoted from**
[docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Answer (score 1):

I use this (in a global styles file) to patch it.

```
.mat-select-trigger { min-width: 50px; }
```