# How to reduce the size of MatSelect DropDown Panel

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

I am trying to reduce the default size of mat-select drop-down panel, But unable to figure out how to do it

I have tried giving width , have tried overriding panel class in angular mat-select, But the size doesn't seem to go down

**My Template File**

```
    <div class="col-md-8">
       <mat-form-field style="float: right">
          <mat-select panelclass="my-panel" placeholder="Select Course"(selectionChange)="selectCourse($event,courses)" disableOptionCentering>
         <mat-option *ngFor="let course of courses" [value]="course.courseId">
          {{course.courseCode}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

**My Css File**

```
 .my-panel {
   background: orange;
   height: 300px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
   min-width: 350px !important;
   }
```

**Expected Result :**

[image: Expected Result]

**Actual Result :**
[image: Actual Result]

[New Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZr2T.png)

Comment: Show your code as well ass your css

Comment: See, if helpful ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092399/mat-select-panel-min-width/53104251#53104251#answer-53104251

Comment: @AbhishekKumar  have tried that it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I think it is because its not able to interpret the X- axis length.

Comment: @BonMacalindong have updated my question you can check.

Comment: @HarshNagalla you can increase height of panel by adding `min-width `property as  `.happy {min-height: 500px;}`

Comment: @AbhishekKumar My concern was not the height actually it is the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your template, it needs to be `panelClass` and not `panelclass`:

```
<mat-select panelClass="my-panel" placeholder="Select Course"(selectionChange)="selectCourse($event,courses)" disableOptionCentering>
```

And as per the documentation [here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview), the `ViewEncapsulation` on your component has to be set to `None` for this to work. It is mentioned in the comment of the example where the `panelClass` is being used:

```
  // Encapsulation has to be disabled in order for the
  // component style to apply to the select panel.
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-3thxee?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) is a working stackblitz that has your style applied to the options.

Comment: Your method seems to be working but some issue with the alignment https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZr2T.png can you plz tell me how to fix this

Comment: Without more information on your components, templates and styles it is extremely difficult to say what the issue is. If I have to guess I would say it is related to your inline style `float: right;` on the `mat-form-field`, try to position it without using float and that might help. But this is not really part of the question anymore, as the class is being applied correctly.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the width of mat-select by adding the below css to the main `styles.css` file.

```
.mat-form-field-infix{
    width: 80px !important;
}
```

Change 80px as per your requirement.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to stretch to the full width of its parent?